# PHP - How to sort Array from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, mysqli

I am retrieving data from a MySQL database with mysqli. I am retrieving rows from the data base, the database has a name and a number for that name and I need the name with the highest number to be printed first, the name with the second highest number to be printed second, and so on...

Here is my code

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {            
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["name"], $row["goals"]);
}
```

Here is the current output

[image]

and I need it so that KaminJack is printed first , BregmanMichael is printed second, and so on

Comment: User `ORDER BY` clause in your query

Answer (score 3):

Your query should be:

`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY goals desc`

Find your data then order by the field `goals` sorting `desc` (or `asc` if you want to).

Comment: @user2109242 desc sorts in descending order(highest to lowest) .. ASC sorts in ascending order (lowest to highest)

Comment: @joschua011 I'd upvote your comment for providing a reference but you used w3schools, so I won't.

Answer (score 1):

To further improve on the answer, you should order by two columns as you have some names with the same number: HidiJack (0) and JainAJesh(0).

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY goals desc, name asc;
```

This will order by the number first, then alphabetically by name.

Or better if you can, make the number an index so that you don't have duplicates.

Comment: Great improvement to my answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could use simply ORDRE BY in MySQL to sort.

But if you want to do it in php:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $result[$row["name"]] = $row["goals"];
}
arsort($result);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php